# Home screen called first before App() is called

Tags: react-native

In react native, even though App is the initial entry point but Home screen is called first. Is it because Home is the initialRouteName defined in the NavigationContainer. If so, then how to initiate Home screen only after App component completes its operation in useEffect method.

```
function App(): JSX.Element {      
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App");
  }, []);
  return (
    <AppNavigation></AppNavigation>
  );
}

const AppNavigation = () => {
return (
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator       >
<Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="home"
      >...
      </Drawer.Navigator>         
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Please check the index.js file:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App)  // Here App is the entry point
```

In your case:
The entry point may changed to home:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => home)
```

Comment: the AppRegistry points to App. So no problem there.

Comment: check out my another solution. @Bibin

Comment: Is that worked for You!

Comment: no, the issue still remains. that code makes no difference than my code.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can try by adding the modified module & line:

```
function App(): JSX.Element {      
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App");
  }, []);
  return (
    <AppNavigation />      //modified line
  );
}


//modified module

const AppNavigation = () => {
return (
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />    //your component
      </Drawer.Navigator>       
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```